# Aggregating result of joined query into a list

Tags: python, mysql

Let me shorten down my requirement and understand it through an example.

Suppose I have two tables
Table 1 = Books

Id : Name : Lcode

1 : book1 :101

2 : book2 :102

3 : book1 :102

Table 2 = Language

Lcode : lname

101 : en

102 : fr

Now I am using this data in mysql to return as json using flask.

I have many such tables in which I need to apply some filter conditions on some columns of 10 such tables.

In output i want every row be like if it has multiple values it should come as a list for example

If I want name and language of book

Book1 : [en,fr]

Boook2 : en

Currently I am using a basic select query using inner join on column lcode
From which i am getting output as

Book1:en

Book1:fr

Book2:en

If I use,

```
Select b.name,l.lname from books b inner join language l on l.lcode=b.lcode group by b.name
```

This will be a wrong sql statement

If I use,

```
Select b.name,l.lname from books b inner join language l on l.lcode=b.lcode group by b.name,l.lname
```

This won't give me correct result

Comment: use `groupby` on top of your joined query

Comment: The problem with group by would be I need to have all columns in group by which are present in select

Comment: I have such total 10 tables from which I need 8-9 columns when all joined together

Comment: select b.book_id,l.code from books_book_languages b inner join books_language l on b.language_id=l.id  group by b.book_id

I obviously wont be able to use this query

Comment: and using this 


select b.book_id,l.code from books_book_languages b inner join books_language l on b.language_id=l.id group by b.book_id,l.code

wont give desired result

Comment: consider book_id as name

Comment: please edit your question to make it more readable with details. A commenty of errata/extra information is hard to read. Your clarification of 'group by' is exceptionally hard to read/understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` is probably what you're after.

Setup

```sql
create table books(
    id serial primary key,
    name text,
    language_id int
);

create table languages(
    id serial primary key,
    name text
);

insert into books(name, language_id) values ('book1', 1), ('book2', 2), ('book1', 2);
insert into languages(name) values ('en'), ('fr');
```

Query

```sql
SELECT
  b.name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(l.name) as languages
FROM 
  books b
INNER JOIN languages l ON b.language_id = l.id
GROUP BY b.name
```

Result

```
name    languages
book1   en,fr
book2   fr
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24e297/3)

Comment: You definitely solved my problem, I never knew such function existed